# Dialogflow Entities - Case sensitive

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a chatbot using Dialogflow and Python and I noticed that the entity names are case-sensitive. Can someone please tell me how to make it case-insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some efficient ways of doing that using Regexp entities but I have not used them extensively, so I am not sure about the side effects. However, the is a simpler way that will certainly work.

On DF console Entities page you can find 'enter synonym' next to your entities reference value. In the synonym section you can enter both capitalized and uncapitalized versions. In that way DF will recognize both options. Similarly you can use Regexp, however that would really depend on how you have structured you entities.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found them to be case sensitive.
Is is possible that other entities are similar enough to others?
Or, do you have fuzzy matching check on any by any chance?

Also, I am still grasping the depths of google cloud console as a whole, but it would seem that a little training does go a long way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32754898)